# ¿Cómo hacer que en una página no aparezca un header, que tengo en un layout, para todos los ficheros html?

Tags: php, mvc, twig

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en clase, utilizando MVC, con twig implementado. Tengo un fichero layout.html, y todo lo que ponga ahí me saldrá en todas las páginas html, por lo tanto ahí tengo un mensaje de bienvenida. Algo así:

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ca">
<head>
    <base href="{{ WEBBASE }}" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{{ TITOL }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ DESCRIPCIO }}" />

    <!--Material Desing Lite-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/material.css">
    <script src="includes/material.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ESTILS }}" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="scripts/salutacio.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<header class="bienvenido">
    <!--<h1>{{ TITOL }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ DESCRIPCIO }}</h2>-->
    <h3>Bienvenido{{ USUARI }}</h3> // Este es el mensaje que sale en todas mis vista, pero que no quiero que salga en dos de ellas
</header>
```

Ese mensaje me sale en todas mis vistas y yo quiero que en la vista de inicio y 
 en la vista de login no me salgan, es decir solo quiero que salga cuando 
 alguien está logueado.

¿Qué podría hacer para que el mensaje no apareciera en esas dos vistas?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas con imágenes en lugar de  código en formato de texto no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: Buenas @DjCrazy, gracias por el aporte, ya lo he corregido, saludos!